# Problems with r packages

Tags: c#, .net, r.net

i have trying to simple code like :

[image]

and then i getting this type Exception : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: null value passing

Comment: yes joji i know then tell me solution how can i solved this.?

Comment: provide the code .